# How to fix 'Cannot override a self return type with a non-self return type' after upgrading Xcode

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, xcode10.2

I'm trying to build an iOS AWS app and I'm having some problems.

I just updated Xcode to version 10.2 and created a brand new project. I'm at the point where I'm trying to install the dependencies with CocoaPods for user authentication. After modifying my podfile to include AWSMobileClient (and running `pod install --repo-update` as the AWS documentation says) I get a build error in the AWSMobileClient.swift in this function:

```swift
@objc override public class func sharedInstance() -> AWSMobileClient {
   return _sharedInstance
}
```

The error says this:

```
Cannot override a Self return type with a non-Self return type
```

I'm pretty darn stuck here and the only thing I can think to do at this point is to go back to Xcode 10.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you suspect XCode is the issue? Was it working in XCode 10.1, and upgrading it broke it?

Comment: I created a new project in XCode 10.1 a few days ago and I never had any problems during the setup. I ended up upgrading this morning to 10.2 and creating a new project and thats when i ran into this problem

Comment: The only solution is to ask AWS to provide a Swift 5 compatibility. Hope you submitted that issue with them.

Answer (score 4):

As a temporary solution make **the class of the method** final.
For example AWSMobileClient now is:

```
public class AWSMobileClient: _AWSMobileClient {
```

Change on this:

```
public final class AWSMobileClient: _AWSMobileClient {
```

And then wait for AWS fixes.

Comment: Thank you so so much!! This solution worked perfectly. I was stuck for 3 days on this I cannot thank you enough!!  Also I submitted this as a bug to AWS so hopefully they can get it figured out on their end. So Stoked!!

Comment: @rolandforbes I'm glad to help! Thank you too for submitting the bug! Also waiting for a solution :)

Answer (score 3):

We ran into this issue but were hesitant to edit the AWSMobileClient directly.

Setting the Swift Language version to 4.2 for the Project and Targets as well as specifying in the Pod file:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
        end
    end
end
```

Worked for us to allow building again. As its a Swift 5 compatibility issue:

[SR-695](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

In Swift 5 mode, a class method returning Self can no longer be overridden with a method returning a non-final concrete class type. Such code is not type safe and will need to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

As the error indicates, you need to return `Self` here if the class is not final.

```
@objc override public class func sharedInstance() -> Self { return _sharedInstance }
```

(This is assuming that `_sharedInstance` is of type `Self`.)

Alternately, you can modify the superclass not to return `Self`, and instead return a specific type (likely its own type).

```
@objc public class func sharedInstance() -> TheActualClass { return _sharedInstance }
```

(All subclasses will in this case need to also return TheActualClass. I assume that class is AWSMobileClient.)

Since this is a framework, I would expect this to be fixed by the vendor, and I would make sure you're running the most up to date version of the framework.

`Self` indicates that this method returns a value of the type of the class being called. So if you have `SomeClass.sharedInstance()` is must return a `SomeClass`. But if you subclass that, then a call to `SubClass.sharedInstance()` must return a `SubClass`. If you can't achieve that, you're going to need to make something final, or not return `Self`.

This is a very strange override, however. It's not clear what this code is trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey Rob! Thanks for the reply. I have tried your solution as well and it returns the following error:  Cannot convert return expression of type 'AWSMobileClient' to return type 'Self'

Comment: How can I modify the superclass to return its own type instead of Self?

Comment: I tried both of these solutions and still getting the same error! Should I be reporting an issue to AWS or Apple? Or both?

Comment: AWS if you're using AWS code and haven't updated to their latest library. Certainly not Apple; there's nothing wrong with Swift. This is a mistake in the framework.

Comment: yea, cos putting bandaid on a 3-rd party library that is clearly incompatible with Swift 5 is such a great idea...